# Get data from two related fact tables based on common date dimension in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

We have two fact tables Fact_Order and Fact_Product.
In fact_Order we have columns OrderId,OrderDate and OrderQuantity.

In fact_Product we have columns ProductReleaseDate and ProductCost

[image: Fact tables]

Now we want to join the Releasedate with all the orders that fall within a week in **MDX**.
Help would be highly appreciated because i am stuck on this from last two days

This is the MDX that i am trying to write for the same.

```
WITH MEMBER [Week1 order] AS
FILTER
    (
        Measures.OrderQuantity, 
        [Release Date].[Date].currentmember : [Release Date].[Date].currentmember.LEAD(6)
    )

SELECT [Week1 order] ON 0,
NON EMPTY
    {
        [Release Date].[Date].[Date],
        FILTER
            (
             [DimOrder].[OrderID].[OrderID], 
             [Release Date].[Date].currentmember : [Release Date].[Date].currentmember.LEAD(6)
            )                   
        ,FILTER
            (
             [Order Date].[Date].[Date], 
             [Release Date].[Date].currentmember : [Release Date].[Date].currentmember.LEAD(6)
            )
    } ON 1 
    FROM 
    [ProductReleaseCube]
```

Comment: Help me in understanding how the tables need to join?? The row with `OrderID 7623` is joined with release date `2015/06/01` because `2015/06/01`(ReleaseDate) is within 7 days from `2015/06/05`?

Comment: actually my release date 2015/06/01 should join with all the order dates that fall with in a week's time from the release date. so here for release date 2015/06/01 it should join with order dates between 2015/06/01 to 2015/06/07.

Comment: Hello @RewatSharma - can you please share some of the `mdx` you've been struggling with the past two days?

Comment: Have you tried using the LinkedMember function?  If your dimensions don't have a relationship in the dimension attributes, but you have a role player date dimension, you can use the function to return related members on different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
WITH SET ValidCombOfDates AS
    FILTER
        (
         NonEmpty
            (
             {
              [Release Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS * [Order Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS
             }, Measures.OrderQuantity
            ),
         [Order Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE - [Release Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE <=7 
        )

MEMBER Measures.ExpectedOrderQuantity AS
    IIF
    (
        ISEMPTY(Measures.OrderQuantity),
        0,
        Measures.OrderQuantity
    )

SELECT 
    ValidCombOfDates * [DimOrder].[OrderID].[OrderID].MEMBERS
ON 1,
    Measures.ExpectedOrderQuantity
ON 0
FROM 
    [ProductReleaseCube]
```